# Controlling a web page, casperJS like : can that be done with chrome extension?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am trying to develop a chrome extension to automtize some tasks on the web (fill form, go to next page, extract data...)

The idea is to develop a kind of http://casperjs.org/ as chrome extension.

I am injecting some JS to an active tab.
JS is run, and everything works fine: **problems raise when I navigate to a new url.**

When the page navigates to new url (document.location for instantce), the JS stops running since it is unloaded.

My idea would be to store the JS state and resume it once page has loaded:

ex content of source variable: I inject it in background to the web page.

```
for (i = 0;i < 5;i++) {
    document.location = "http://www.example.com/page"+i;
    waitUntilPageIsLoaded();

    var source = $("body").html();
    extractData(source);
}
```

> chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, { code: source });

Of course this does not work since we change the location of the page.

Or more generally speaking, can casperJS can be developped using google chrome extension ?

Comment: Maybe you can simply reinject the content script in [`chrome.tabs.onUpdated` listener](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#event-onUpdated)?

Comment: yes, but I will start the script from begin. Imagine the script that loops over pages : it will extract page1 for ever. I changes the question and edited there a loop script.

Comment: Do that loop in the background script and use `chrome.tabs.update` instead of `document.location` to change the url, then inject the content script, repeat.

Comment: I do that in background script already: The background script injects this script to the page and executes it: works fine. BUt of course when page changes, the injected script is destroyed and if I run it again on "onUpdated", it will start form scratch and not continue when it stopped before unloading

Comment: No, the idea was different. However, I guess, the question doesn't contain enough information because it's not clear why you can't reinject the script and pass it the new state either via `chrome.tabs.executeScript` or `chrome.runtime.sendMessage`.